# oninput="function()" works with textarea, but not div, in Safari. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

Testing in, and for use with, Safari 11.0.1 under OSX 10.12.6;

I would like to use `oninput="function()"` in a `<div>` with `contenteditable="true"` set. Bare-bones test page case works with `<textarea>`, but not `<div>`. Here's the test code; change script first var load `getElementById` parameter to *dpagecontentx* from *tpagecontentx* to see it work with textarea and not work with div.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>
      function onCharInput()
      {
        var conpagechars = document.getElementById("tpagecontentx").value;
        var conpagecharcount = conpagechars.length.toString();
        document.getElementById("pccount").innerHTML = conpagecharcount;
      }
    </SCRIPT>
    <title>Editor</title>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <center>
      <div id="dpagecontentx" oninput="onCharInput()" name="dpagecontent" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Courier; padding: .5em; text-align: left; border-color: #000000; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; width: 60em; height: 24em;"></div>
      <TEXTAREA id="tpagecontentx" oninput="onCharInput()" NAME="tpagecontent" ROWS=10 COLS=80>foo</TEXTAREA>
    </center>
    <p>
      Content Size: <span id="pccount"></span>
    </p>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oninput` event is only fired when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is changed, For a `<div>` tag You can  use `keyup` event to detect changes, Here is working example:

```js
function onCharInput(e)
{
  // here I use tagName property to get the element content
  // according to its type
  if (e.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
    var conpagechars = document.getElementById("dpagecontentx").innerText; 
  } else {
    var conpagechars = document.getElementById("tpagecontentx").value;
  }

  var conpagecharcount = conpagechars.length.toString();
  document.getElementById("pccount").innerHTML = conpagecharcount;
}
```

```html
<center>
<div id="dpagecontentx" onkeyup="onCharInput(event)" name="dpagecontent" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Courier; padding: .5em; text-align: left; border-color: #000000; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; width: 60em; height: 24em;"></div>
<TEXTAREA id="tpagecontentx" oninput="onCharInput(event)" NAME="tpagecontent" ROWS=10 COLS=80>foo</TEXTAREA>
</center>
<p>
Content Size: <span id="pccount"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful info about the inconsistent application of `oninput`. Your overall solution works, sort of, but when a key is held down, e.g. the backspace, the count will not update until the key is released. `onkeydown` happens before the keystroke is added to the div. Both are problematic because what I need is notification when the content of the div has changed. So keystrokes, paste, cut, etc., all work.

Comment: I searched everywhere, but I can't find a good solution to the problem, maybe someone can help us

Comment: I've been looking too. I very much appreciate your answer and your time. I'm marking your answer as the accepted one, because I think it's as good an answer as there is, besides, you caught the bit about the  `oninput` implementation, which was stopping me cold. It never even occurred to me that an an actual field intended for input wouldn't support `oninput`. I've gone with a preview implementation because making an editor is ridiculously complex with the current state of HTML/CSS. Perhaps they'll get it right with the next iteration. Thanks again.

Comment: [Previewer.](http://ourtimelines.com/aamacropreview.html) - wanted a live editor, but this will have to do. Looking around the web, I see this kind of thing a lot. So... :)

Comment: You are welcome @fyngyrz, I think you can do a live editor, it's not impossible but there are many events you have to listen to in order to detect div changes, for example keydown, oncontextmenu (mouse right click), ctrl + v (paste), ctrl + x (cut), ... but it will be a pain, also the plugins available are most ugly and heavy...

Comment: hence... previewer. :)